# Add column of Row numbers where row is not blank or does not start with [

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to achieve the following row numbering:

| Count |  |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | A |
|  | [A |
| 02 | A |
|  |  |
| 03 | A |

So basically any line thats blank or starts with a `[` is ignored in the count

I've tried modifying this formula so that it also ignores cells that start with a `[`

```
={"Sr. No.";ArrayFormula(ifna(vlookup(row(B2:B),{filter(row(B2:B),B2:B<>""),sequence(counta(B2:B),1)},2,0)))}
```

The above works fine but when I added in `regexmatch(B2:B, "^[^\[])` ie.

```
={"Sr. No.";ArrayFormula(ifna(vlookup(row(B2:B),{filter(row(B2:B),B2:B<>"",regexmatch(B2:B, "^[^\[])),sequence(counta(B2:B),1)},2,0)))}
```

It fails :-(

Any help/alternate approaches would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

The `filter` and `sequence` formulas with the added condition `[` now have different number of columns (in my example, 4 vs 5), thus returning an error.

### Solution:

This can be fixed by adding `-countif(LEFT(B2:B),"[")` to the `sequence` formula:

```
={"Sr. No.";ArrayFormula(ifna(vlookup(row(B2:B),{filter(row(B2:B),B2:B<>"",LEFT(B2:B)<>"["),sequence(counta(B2:B)-countif(LEFT(B2:B),"["),1)},2,0)))}
```

Please note that I used `LEFT` instead of regex, it does the same text condition.

**Sample:**

[image]